# vba code that runs fine in Excel 2007 will not run in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I have some vba code that adds user names and passwords to set user edit ranges.
The code works beautifully in Excel 2007 but when I try to run it in Excel 2013 I keep getting a Runtime error 1004 Application defined or object defined error.
The code stops at the line  set erTimeInputs.
I believe it is because the variable erTimeInputs has a value of nothing but I cannot get it to accept a value.  I have tried to define it as various data types but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
Sub AddUserEditRanges()

'Update username and password before running this macro

Dim UserNameArr() As Variant
Dim UserRangeArr()  As Variant
Dim UserPsswdArr() As Variant
Dim v As Variant
Dim LastUserRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, UserRange As Range, aer As AllowEditRange
Dim UserName As String
Dim Psswd As String
Dim erTimeInputs as Variable

'Find number of users
LastUserRow = Range("A170").End(xlDown).Row

'set arrays
UserNameArr = Range("B168:B" & LastUserRow).Value
UserPsswdArr = Range("C168:C" & LastUserRow).Value
UserRangeArr = Range("D168:D" & LastUserRow).Value

    For v = LBound(UserNameArr) To UBound(UserNameArr)

    UserName = UserNameArr(v, 1)
    UserRange = UserRangeArr(v, 1)
    Psswd = UserPsswdArr(v, 1)

        'Add edit ranges to the worksheets for all users.
       Set erTimeInputs = _
              Worksheets("Week1").Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add(Title:= _
              UserName, Range:=Worksheets("Week1") _
              .Range(UserRange), Password:=Psswd)

        Set erTimeInputs = _
              Worksheets("Week2").Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add(Title:= _
              UserName, Range:=Worksheets("Week2") _
              .Range(UserRange), Password:=Psswd)
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim erTimeInputs as Variable` This line is definitely wrong. There is no `Variable` type. Perhaps you're thinking of `Variant`, like the other types you've defined?

Comment: You can declare it as `Variant` as what @CodyGray commented or you can explicitly declare it as: `Dim erTimeInputs As AllowEditRange`.

Comment: Sorry the Variable is simply my typo error.  I have tried declaring it as Variant, AllowEditRange, Range and may other types without success.

Answer (score 2):

As commented you can declare your variable as `AllowEditRange` variable type explicitly.
Now, there should be no problem as long as the ***Title*** you assign to it does not exist, else it will throw the run-time error.
I don't know why you need to set or assign it to a variable object, but if what you want is just to add username and password, you can do it without assigning it to a variable.

```
For v = LBound(UserNameArr) To UBound(UserNameArr)
    UserName = UserNameArr(v, 1)
    UserRange = UserRangeArr(v, 1)
    Psswd = UserPsswdArr(v, 1)
    'Check if worksheet is unprotected and ready for editing
    If Worksheet("Week1").ProtecContents = True Then Msgbox "Unprotect Sheet first", _
        vbCritical: Exit Sub

    'Add edit ranges to the worksheets for all users.
    If AllowEditExist(UserName, Worksheets("Week1")) Then
        'Delete Existing
        Worksheets("Week1").Protection.AllowEditRanges(UserName).Delete
    End If
        'Add New 
    Worksheets("Week1").Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Ttle:= _
        UserName, Range:=Worksheets("Week1") _
        .Range(UserRange), Password:=Psswd
Next
```

**Edit1:** Below routine will check if the *AllowEditRange* already exist.

```
Function AllowEditExist(mytitle As String, sh As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim a As AllowEditRange: AllowEditExist = False
    For Each a In sh.Protection.AllowEditRanges
        If a.Title = mytitle Then
            AllowEditExist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**Important:** You should unprotect the worksheets before you add, delete *AllowEditRanges*, it will generate error otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I am still getting the same 1004 error when I run the code you have suggested without the variable.  As stated this has been working for quite some time in 2007 but the error is encountered when I run it in 2013

Comment: @James42 Have you tried checking if the *AllowEditRange* already exist? I'll update my post and include a routine which will check if the *AllowEditRange* already exist.

Comment: @James42 I think above code will work in XL2013 which most likely had covered the cause of runtime. You can also choose to unprotect the sheet if you want during runtime instead of showing a `MsgBox`.

Comment: Appreciate the effort guys but still no go.  I unprotect the sheets at the beginning of the routine I just didn't include that code, also the AllowEditRanges are all cleared before this is run so the title definitely does not exist.

Comment: Thanks again for your assistance and it seems that you have put your finger on it.  I had commented out the routine to clear the titles and of course there was one title still hanging around in one of the worksheets.  My error this time, so thanks again and sorry for the red herring.